# How to keep firefox web extension popup from closing when clicking on inspector window

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm having a hard time debugging my Firefox extension (popup). Whenever I click on the debug pane, the popup closes and all the information in the debug pane is gone. This happens when trying to inspect the network requests, copy something from the console, or look at the element styles in the inspector.

I'm sure other Firefox extension devs have encountered this problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable popups closing when something outside of it is focused from the add-on debugger toolbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Debugging_popups

Answer (score -1):

Click Disable Popup Auto-Hide option in the extension console, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxuzO.png)